# Vim enclose in quotes

Tags: vim

Say I have the following

```
printf(text goes here);
```

and I select "text goes here" in visual mode...
How do I quickly change it to

```
printf("text goes here");
```

Comment: OP: "How do I quickly do X". Top answer: `:s/\%V\(.*\)\%V/"\1"/`

Comment: TLDR dear googlers: https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is intended to answer the specific question that you asked.  You state that you have visually selected some text and want to surround it with quotes. To do that, run:

```
:s/\%V\(.*\)\%V/"\1"/
```

To break that into parts:

- `:` allows you to enter `ex` commands.
- `s/old/new/` is the usual substitute command.
- `\%V` is an under-documented atom to mark the beginning of the selected text
- `\(.*\)` selects everything and save it into selection 1.
- The second `\%V` signifies the end of the selected text.
- The replacement text is everyting that was selected, which is stored in `\1`, surrounded by quotes: `"\1"`.

This command applies line by line. So, you may get unwanted results if the selected text extends over multiple lines.

Comment: I think there's a bug. `printf(text goes here);` becomes `printf("text goes her"e);`.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu It is not clear to me if that is a `vim` bug or not.  In either case, a simple workaround is to highlight one extra character.

Comment: For the record, I used with vim-enhanced-7.4.179-1.fc20.x86_64.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu @John1024 %V just matches the selection up to before the cursor, therefor if the `e` is the last character in the selection, then the second %V is not inside the selection and ignores the last `e`.

Comment: @John1024 the real work around would be to use the more appropriate '<,'> or in a pinch include a `.` after the second \%V

Comment: vnoremap <leader>" <esc>`>a"<esc>`<i"<esc>

Comment: This works for me (adding the second `\%V` and a dot in the captured region: `'<,'>s/\%V\(.*\%V.\)/"\1"/`

Answer (score 28):

You should research more. [What Vim command(s) can be used to quote/unquote words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147875/what-vim-commands-can-be-used-to-quote-unquote-words)

Quoting:

> [**surround.vim**](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) is going to be your easiest answer.  If you are truly set
>   against using it, here are some examples for what you can do.  Not
>   necessarily the most efficient, but that's why surround.vim was
>   written.
>
> - Quote a word, using single quotes   `ciw'Ctrl+r"'`
>
>   - `ciw` - Delete the word the cursor is on, and end up in insert mode.
>   - `'` - add the first quote.
>   - `Ctrl+r"` - Insert the contents of the `"` register, aka the last yank/delete.
>   - `'` - add the closing quote.
> - Unquote a word that's enclosed in single quotes   `di'hPl2x`
>
>   - `di'` - Delete the word enclosed by single quotes.
>   - `hP` - Move the cursor left one place (on top of the opening quote) and put the just deleted text before the quote.
>   - `l` - Move the cursor right one place (on top of the opening quote).
>   - `2x` - Delete the two quotes.
> - Change single quotes to double quotes   `va':s/\%V'\%V/"/g`
>
>   - `va'` - Visually select the quoted word and the quotes.
>   - `:s/` - Start a replacement.
>   - `\%V'\%V` - Only match single quotes that are within the visually selected region.
>   - `/"/g` - Replace them all with double quotes.

Comment: tl;dr Install [**surround.vim**](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround), visually select the text then press `S"`.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu `ysi)"` without visual mode.

Comment: that's a different question

Answer (score 23):

The command sequence `cw""<ESC>P` is the close thing that can do a surrounding of text and works by cutting the word (string of alphanumeric characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ [underscore]), then inserts the text `""`, and hitting the escape key (`<ESC>` to escape out of insert mode one then is able to paste before the cursor. Thus the command breaks down to:

`c` - cut into register

`w` - regex match \w

`""`  - insert two `"` characters at current cursor position

`<ESC>` - VIM shorthand for hitting the escape key. In this context, return to command mode

`P` - paste current register

However, in the case of longer sets of strings on the current line that one wishes to surround, one would need to use substitution regex commands with a capture group such as:

`:s/\(\w\+\)/"\1"/g`

This command stores the resulting matched regex captured as group '1' and preform substitution to insert the group's contents inside your quotes. Thus, given the text:

```
fubar: 1
```

Becomes:

```
"fubar": 1
```

The [vim intro](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html) help file is one of the best resources for anyone, along with the `:help` command.

Comment: This works great with visual mode as well

Comment: I think a small improvement is to use ciw""<ESC>P because you can be with the cursor in the middle of the word and you can do "change inner word".

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I quoted a few of my visual selections:

1. While in VISUAL mode select the text you need to quote, then press `qqc""<Esc>Pq`

   - `qq` begins recording your actions into record q
   - `c` puts selected text in a register and switches to INPUT mode
   - `""` puts symbols you need to enclose the text with
   - `<Esc>` switches to NORMAL mode
   - `P` puts the text from the register in the cursor position, in-between quotes
   - `q` denotes the end of actions recording
2. Now, whithin the same session, you will be able to quote any visual block by just typing `@q`, which playbacks our previosly recorded actions
3. ???
4. After using `@q` once you will be able issue `@@` (repeat previous action) to quote subsequent visual selections

Comment: What is step 3? Please fix you answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use visual mode. Simply change the text in the parens to "", and then paste the deleted text in between.
ci)""*<Esc>*P

If you want to use visual mode, it works the same, you just drop the 'i)' part:
c""*<Esc>*P

(*<Esc>* means hit the escape key)

Answer (score 2):

Using the plugin `surround.vim` which seems to be enabled by default in modern Vim installations (at least in Ubuntu 20):

1. Visually select text to be surrounded
2. Type `S"` to surround the text with double quotes

Taken from [Christian Ciupitu's](https://superuser.com/users/2357/cristian-ciupitu) excellent comment which is unfortunately buried down under the last question.

Answer (score 2):

```
:s/\(\%V\(.*\)\%V.\)/"\1"/
```

Based on the other answers, `%V` matches up to one character before the end of the selection. So an extra char matching is included.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using vim-surround plugin
https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround

```
ysiw"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I use surround.vim

```
cs"' or cs'" -> change surroundings <from> - <to>
```

> Surround.vim is all about "surroundings": parentheses, brackets,
> quotes, XML tags, and more. The plugin provides mappings to easily
> delete, change and add such surroundings in pairs.

https://github.com/tpope/vim-surroundl